# Exactly how does one lope on the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, astronauts, astronaut-lifestyle, reduced-gravity-sports

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40322/12102) includes several quotes from apollo astronauts that have walked on the moon. They describe a form of bipedal locomotion they call loping.

**Question:** Exactly how does one lope on the Moon? Is it possible to describe in text? See for example the first few sentences of Wikipedia's [trot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trot) or [cantor and gallup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canter_and_gallop) for how this can be done effectively.

Video links may be helpful additions to an answer, but the answer should explain/describe how to do it and what's involved. Thanks!

Comment: `reduced-gravity-sports` might be a bit of a stretch but understanding methods bipedal motion in reduced gravity is important so I think future readers will find answers to this question helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Moon Loping** is a form of legged lunar locomotion performed by humans on the natural Earth satellite (the Moon) where the human propels itself through a space above the lunar surface along a ballistic trajectory with relatively long duration of the floating phase.

[Lunar gaits page](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11.gaits.html)
 gives the following description:

> Most of the astronauts on the later missions favored a loping gait in which they still alternated feet but **pushed off with each step and floated forward before planting the next foot**. Ed Mitchell of Apollo 14 and Gene Cernan on Apollo 17 favored a skipping stride in which they kept one foot always forward, let's say the left and, as they landed, hit with the trailing foot just a fraction of a second before the leading foot, pushing off with each foot as it hit and launching into the next glide.

Same source quotes Armstrong's explanaition:

> Armstrong, from the 1969 Technical Debrief - "I can best describe a lope as **having both feet off the ground at the same time**, as opposed to walking where you have one foot on the ground at all times. In loping, you **leave the ground with both feet and come down with one foot** in a normal running fashion. It's not like an Earth run here, because you are taking advantage of the low gravity."

Emphasis mine.

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like there's moon loping demonstrated at 4:47 in this video:

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was sure that this one would have spike to the top of the HNQ, my gosh who on Earth wouldn't want to know exactly how to lope on the Moon? ;-)

Comment: They are about double the earths mass due to their heavy suit. Without this weight and mass one would presumably jump farther.